# printing json object content with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, puppeteer, cheerio

this is the code I use to save the scraped json data and save it, the exact same way it was scraped. The console.log result is from console.log(testObj).

However, if I console.log(testObj.name) or anything else, it ends up "undefined". I want to console.log the availability content. So making it result in console.log(testObj.offers.availibility) = InStock.

If anyone could help that would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance! :)

```
            let testObj = {}

            let content = JSON.stringify($("script[type='application/ld+json']").html())
            let filteredJson = content.replace(/\\n/g, '')
            let results = JSON.parse(filteredJson)
            
            testObj = [JSON.parse(results)]
            console.log(testObj)
```

testObj content

[image]

I need to scrape the product name, stock status and price and save it to an object from this piece of text:

```
<script type="application/ld+json>
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "Nintendo Switch Animal Crossing Editie",
    "description": "&lt;div class=&quot;textblock&quot;&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;h2&gt;Nintendo Switch Animal Crossing: New Horizons-editie&lt;/h2&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;color: #00b050;&quot;&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Dit betreft de Nintendo Switch met verbeterde batterijduur (modelnummer MOD. HAC-001-&lt;span style=&quot;text-decoration: underline;&quot;&gt;01&lt;/span&gt;).&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Deze speciale Nintendo Switch-bundel bevat alles wat je nodig hebt voor je nieuwe eilandleven: een spelsysteem, een houder, Joy-Con-controllers en polsbandjes met een speciaal eilandthema en een downloadcode voor Animal Crossing: New Horizons!&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Deze bundel bevat:&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;ul&gt;
    &lt;li&gt;Nintendo Switch systeem&lt;/li&gt;
    &lt;li&gt;Linker en rechter Joy-Con controllers&lt;/li&gt;
    &lt;li&gt;Nintendo Switch Dock&lt;/li&gt;
    &lt;li&gt;Joy-Con Grip&lt;/li&gt;
    &lt;li&gt;Joy-Con Straps (2x)&lt;/li&gt;
    &lt;li&gt;AC adapter&lt;/li&gt;
    &lt;li&gt;HDMI-kabel&lt;/li&gt;
    &lt;li&gt;Downloadcode voor Animal Crossing: New Horizons&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;
&lt;p&gt;
De Nintendo Switch biedt je de kans om dezelfde games te spelen waar, wanneer en met wie je wil. De Nintendo Switch combineert de flexibiliteit van een handheld-systeem met de kracht van een systeem voor thuis, wat gloednieuwe manieren biedt om games te spelen.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;De Nintendo Switch is een revolutionair gamesysteem. Niet alleen kun je het thuis aansluiten op de tv, maar je kunt het ook in een handomdraai veranderen in een handheldsysteem met een beeldscherm van 6,2 inch, waarop je onderweg kunt spelen. Voor het eerst kan je altijd en overal genieten van de ervaring die gamesystemen voor thuis bieden. Het scherm is een geavanceerd touchscreen met multi-touchmogelijkheden voor compatibele games. De batterij kan van vier en een half tot negen uur meegaan, afhankelijk van de game en de omstandigheden waarin het systeem wordt gebruikt.&amp;nbsp;Als je niet thuis bent, kun je de Nintendo Switch opladen door de voeding aan te sluiten op de USB Type-C-poort van het systeem.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;h3&gt;Thuis en onderweg&lt;/h3&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Thuis kun je de Nintendo Switch in de Nintendo Switch-houder zetten, waarmee je het systeem op de tv kunt aansluiten. Zo kun je samen met je vrienden en familie in je woonkamer spelen. Zodra je de Nintendo Switch uit de houder haalt, wordt de handheldstijl automatisch ingeschakeld. De geweldige game-ervaring die je thuis beleefde, kun je dan onderweg voortzetten. De Nintendo Switch is voorzien van een helder HD-beeldscherm. Hiermee kun je de game-ervaring die je gewend bent van spelsystemen voor thuis ook beleven in het park, in de trein, in de auto of bij een vriend thuis.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;h3&gt;Ge&amp;iuml;ntegreerde Joy-Con controllers&lt;/h3&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Met de veelzijdige Joy-Con controllers kunnen spelers op diverse, verrassende nieuwe manieren plezier hebben. Je kan in iedere hand &amp;eacute;&amp;eacute;n Joy-Con-controller houden of ze als &amp;eacute;&amp;eacute;n controller gebruiken door ze vast te maken aan de Joy-Con  Grip. De controllers kunnen ook worden vastgemaakt aan het systeem zelf om het in de handheldstijl te gebruiken. Bij ondersteunde games voor twee spelers houdt iedere speler &amp;eacute;&amp;eacute;n controller vast. Iedere Joy-Con heeft een volledige serie knoppen, zodat elke controller los kan worden gebruikt. Elke Joy-Con heeft ook een versnellingsmeter en een gyroscoop, waardoor de linker- en rechtercontroller elk hun eigen bewegingsbesturing hebben.&amp;nbsp;&lt;br&gt;
&lt;br&gt;
De Nintendo Switch beschikt over een aantal ingebouwde functies die het systeem interactiever maken. Op de linker-Joy-Con zit een opnameknop waar je op kunnen drukken om screenshots te maken in games. Deze screenshots kan je vervolgens delen met vrienden op social media. Op de rechter-Joy-Con zit een NFC-aanraakpunt waar je amiibo-figuurtjes tegenaan kunt houden, evenals een infrarood-bewegingscamera die naast de afstand ook de vorm en bewegingen van objecten herkent in bepaalde games. De camera ziet bijvoorbeeld hoe ver weg de hand van een speler is en ziet zelfs het verschil tussen de handgebaren steen, papier en schaar. &lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Beide Joy-Con controllers zijn uitgerust met een nieuwe HD-trilfunctie die in compatibele games zorgt voor verfijnde trillingen die realistischer zijn dan ooit tevoren. Het effect is zo realistisch dat je bijvoorbeeld kan voelen hoe meerdere ijsblokjes elkaar raken in een glas, wanneer een Joy-Con wordt geschud. De HD-trilfunctie brengt een realistische ervaring teweeg waar beelden en geluiden alleen niet voor kunnen zorgen.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;h3&gt;Multiplayer&lt;/h3&gt;
&lt;p&gt;De Nintendo Switch geeft je de mogelijkheid om gemakkelijk samen te spelen. Maximaal acht systemen kunnen met elkaar worden verbonden voor draadloze lokale multiplayer. Dankzij de ingebouwde standaard kan je het systeem overal rechtop zetten en de Joy-Con-controllers verdelen om samen te spelen als er geen tv in de buurt is. &lt;/p&gt;
&lt;ul&gt;
    &lt;li&gt;Plaats de Switch in de Switch Dock om games op je tv te spelen&lt;/li&gt;
    &lt;li&gt;Schuif de Joy-Con-controllers op de Switch en neem hem met je mee als een handheld console&lt;/li&gt;
    &lt;li&gt;Speel co-op of competitieve multiplayer games met twee door elk gebruik te maken van &amp;eacute;&amp;eacute;n Joy-Con controller&lt;/li&gt;
    &lt;li&gt;Gebruik GameCards om games af te spelen&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;
&lt;h3&gt;Nintendo Switch Online&lt;/h3&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Nintendo maakte ook een nieuwe online service bekend genaamd Nintendo Switch Online. Deze betaalde dienst is vereist om bepaalde games te kunnen spelen, zoals Mario Kart 8 Deluxe, Mario Tennis Aces, Splatoon 2 en alle toekomstige online games. Gratis games zoals Fortnite Battle Royale kunnen ook zonder abonnement online worden gespeeld! De Nintendo Switch Online service biedt tal van voordelen:&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;ul&gt;
    &lt;li&gt;Online Multiplayer - Speel online met of tegen anderen&lt;/li&gt;
    &lt;li&gt;Nintendo Switch Online App - Houd contact met vrienden via de speciale app op je smartphone of tablet&lt;/li&gt;
    &lt;li&gt;Opslagclouddienst - Maak cloudback-ups van je opgeslagen gegevens en meer&lt;/li&gt;
    &lt;li&gt;Nintendo Entertainment System Nintendo Switch Online - Speel een groeiende collectie klassieke games met toegevoegde onlinestanden&lt;/li&gt;
    &lt;li&gt;Exclusieve aanbiedingen voor leden - Profiteer van aanbiedingen die alleen beschikbaar zijn voor leden&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;
&lt;div class=&quot;textblock&quot;&gt;
&lt;p&gt;
&lt;style&gt;
    .textblock img {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 20px 10px 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
&lt;/style&gt;
&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;h2&gt;Animal Crossing: New Horizons&lt;/h2&gt;
&lt;img alt=&quot;Nederlands&quot; style=&quot;float: left;&quot; src=&quot;https://gamemania-sec.azureedge.net/-/media/Sites/GameMania/Products/Games/A/ANIMAL-CROSSING/Animal-Crossing-New-Horizons/Screenshots/Nederlanstalig-button.jpg?la=nl-NL&amp;amp;hash=7038D18C487B151E39AA0FD0C242ED847C0B788F&quot; width=&quot;150&quot;&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Als je in de put zit door de waan van de dag, dan heeft Tom Nook de perfecte oplossing voor je: zijn gloednieuwe, superexclusieve Eilandleven-pakket!&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Je hebt overal kleurrijke personages ontmoet. Je hebt mogen proeven aan het stadsleven. Je hebt misschien zelfs een tijdje een publieke functie bekleed! Maar schuilt er niet iets in je dat smacht naar&amp;hellip; vrijheid? Gewoon doen waar je zin in hebt, wanneer het jou uitkomt? Een lange strandwandeling op een onbewoond eiland met ongerepte natuur is wellicht precies wat de dokter je heeft voorgeschreven!&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Geniet van een zorgeloos bestaan vol creativiteit en geef het leven vorm hoe jij dat wilt.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Verzamel grondstoffen en maak er de mooiste spullen van, zoals meubilair en gereedschap. Groene vingers? Leg je eigen tuintje aan en plant bloemen en bomen op geheel nieuwe wijze. Bouw de woning van je dromen en geniet van het eilandleven.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Word vrienden met nieuwe bewoners, geniet van de seizoenen, spring met een polsstok over rivieren terwijl je het eiland verkent, en nog veel meer!&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;ul&gt;
    &lt;li&gt;Pas je personage en thuis aan en versier het landschap (met meubels, als je wilt!) om je eigen eilandparadijs te maken.&lt;/li&gt;
    &lt;li&gt;Ga aan de slag met het nieuwe craftingsysteem: verzamel materialen op het eiland om van alles te bouwen, van meubilair tot gereedschap!&lt;/li&gt;
    &lt;li&gt;Je kunt volledig tot rust komen met ontspannen activiteiten, zoals tuinieren, vissen, versieren, een praatje maken met interessante personages en meer.&lt;/li&gt;
    &lt;li&gt;Bekende Animal Crossing-gameplay komt op allerlei leuke en nieuwe manieren tot leven op het onbewoonde eiland.&lt;/li&gt;
    &lt;li&gt;Er kunnen maximaal acht spelers op een eiland wonen. Vier bewoners van hetzelfde eiland kunnen tegelijkertijd op hetzelfde systeem spelen.&lt;/li&gt;
    &lt;li&gt;Via de online- of lokale draadloze multiplayerstand kunnen tot wel acht spelers op het eiland van een speler spelen.&lt;/li&gt;
    &lt;li&gt;Je nieuwe huis staat nog in de steigers. Misschien vind je deze andere Animal Crossing-games ook wel interessant voordat je gaat verhuizen!&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt;",
    "brand": {
        "@type": "Thing",
        "name": "Game Mania"
    },
    "aggregateRating": {
        "@type": "AggregateRating",
        "ratingValue": "4",
        "ratingCount": "541"
    },
    "offers": {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "priceCurrency": "EUR",
        "price": "379",
        "availability" : "InStock"
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why is the JSON in a `<script>` tag? You shouldn't need to `JSON.stringify($(anything).html())`. `.html()` is already a String. Under this strange script tag way it would be like `const testObj = JSON.parse($("script[type='application/ld+json']").html().replace(/\\n/g/, '')); console.log(testObj['02:11:02.159'].name);`.

Comment: Can you paste the data as well. So we can test it locally/

Comment: testObj = [JSON.parse(results)] here you are assigning it to array and after that testObj.name will be ```undefined```

Comment: I edited the question with the data from the website im trying to scrape to make it a little more clear what im doing

Answer (score 0):

That's not json, json has double quotes for keys and string values. You can try `eval`ing it (which isn't really safe) or look into node vm

Comment: I added the website script content underneath my question. Pretty sure its JSON? I don't know why my object doesn't contain the double quotes.Correct me if im wrong tho.